# Full Group BY error in order and select clause

Tags: php, mysql

I've a temp table which results this -

```
number   contact_id      email           email_id
 8       204         ask@gmail.com           185
 8       205         ask@gmail.com           186
```

I need to fetch the result grouping the query with `email` column.

When I try this -

```
SELECT number, contact_id, email_id 
        FROM       contact 
       GROUP BY email
      ORDER BY   contact_id, email_id
```

It gives a `FULL_GROUP_BY` error as

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column...

When I modify the select clause to use `ANY_VALUE` keyword as

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(number), ANY_VALUE(contact_id), ANY_VALUE(email_id)
```

It gives an error as -

> Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'contact_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is there any way I could group the result by `email` and return only one row ?

Eg either

```
8       204         ask@gmail.com           185`
```

OR

```
8       205         ask@gmail.com           186
```

Note: I need to do this keeping `only_full_group_by` mode enabled (MySQL 5.7+). Also I can't remove any `order_by` clause.

Comment: Use `SELECT number, contact_id, email_id, email  FROM contact  GROUP BY email ORDER BY   contact_id, email_id`

Comment: Thanks, but that will error in select list not in group by as contact_id is not in group by and if we do that - it will result both the rows, I want any one row to be returned

Comment: Use : `SELECT min(number), email FROM contact GROUP BY email ORDER BY contact_id, email_id`

Comment: Tried that too - that results in `ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add what exactly you expect the result look like?! How exactly do you want to combine two rows in 1 row?! because it seems to be a very simple query!

Comment: @EhsanT Any of the two row displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this with below query. If anyone has a better way, please post as an answer.

```
   SELECT ANY_VALUE(number), ANY_VALUE(contact_id), ANY_VALUE(email_id)
    FROM       contact 
   GROUP BY email
   ORDER BY   MIN(contact_id), MIN(email_id)
```