# ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

I am unable to fetch data from database at my server I am using ubantu 16.04 and `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`.
It is showing error

```
2018-01-08 09:18:04 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Expression #7 of SELECT
list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
 db11.billpaidde6_.id' which is not functionally dependent on 
columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
 sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have checked all queries that are working in my local host but showing error in server how to resolve this

Comment: You are running a query that is causing this error. Can you post it?

Comment: You may wish to change the `sql_mode` from [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Comment: This is working in my local host. will query change be resolve this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37248560/876739 solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because `sql_mode` is set to [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757561/full-group-by-error-in-order-and-select-clause). This setting means that MySQL will error when you select data that you are not aggregating in any way and you have a `GROUP BY` in your query.

This will take effect in the following scenario:

```
table: users
id | name  | favourite_colour
----------------------------
1  | Fred  | blue
2  | John  | green
3  | David | blue
```

Take the following query:

```
SELECT id, favourite_colour FROM users GROUP BY favourite_colour
```

If you were MySQL, what would you return for the `id` column? For the row that is grouping `green` it's an easy choice because there will only be 1 aggregation. However, for the colour `blue` there are 2 rows being aggregated. In reality MySQL will choose one of the `id`'s to show for you but I do not think it is reliable.

Another query that could trigger this error would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY favourite_colour
```

This is still selecting columns that are not aggregated in any way, and will still fail.

---

You can resolve this error by omitting any non-aggregated columns from your query, or aggregating the ones that you may care about.

```
SELECT favourite_colour FROM users GROUP BY favourite_colour
SELECT count(*), favourite_colour FROM users GROUP BY favourite_colour
```

Alternatively you can disable this SQL mode.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))
```

The above command will not set the `sql_mode` global permanently. Please find the line (or similar) in `my.cnf` and remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

```
[mysqld] 
sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
```

If you do not have access to the server then you will need to contact your hosting provider and ask them to turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: I tried simple one `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))` this is not doing anything

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT @@sql_mode`? I have also updated the answer with instructions to make this change permanent.

Comment: I am getting ` SELECT @@sql_mode;                                                                                                                            
 ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |